# Calculate angle of view from 2D image

Tags: math, trigonometry

I want to calculate the angle of view (or the field of view) from a photograph, without knowing anything about the camera, as to use that information in a 3D environment.

I have to use trigonometry to solve this (most probably using arctan), but I'm not proficient enough in math ...
Can somebody please help?

Please have a look at this [example](http://blackbox.navigram.com/dickl/example.png).

I assume the angle between the line CENTER-LEFT and CENTER-RIGHT is 90° in reality.

I know the distances (in pixels) of point C to the vanishing points VP-left and VP-right.

Furthermore the height of the image is the angle of view in my 3D environment.

Thanks!

Comment: The angle of view, from where? For the camera which took this photo or else?

Comment: Indeed the angle of view of the camera.